# Converting a with statement to a togglable if

Tags: javascript, if-statement, bookmarklet

I am trying to make a bookmarklet that I can use to quickly toggle the `class`/`id` of elements. I found this [old] code for toggling highlighting links. I have read that the `with` statement should be avoided unless you are using `use strict;`. I couldn't find any walk through on how `with` would look like `if`, and not sure how it would look

```js
javascript: for (nIx5Bs = 0; nIx5Bs < document.all.length; nIx5Bs++) {
  if (document.all[nIx5Bs].tagName == 'A') {
    with(document.all[nIx5Bs].style) {
      if (backgroundColor == 'yellow') {
        void(backgroundColor = document.bgColor)
      } else {
        void(backgroundColor = 'yellow')
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I found another bookmarklet to show `id`s, but it isn't togglable.

```js
javascript: var t = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
for (i = 0; i < t.length; i++) {
  void(t[i].style.padding = '5px;');
  b = t[i].className;
  h = t[i].innerHTML;
  void(t[i].innerHTML = '<p style=\'color:red;font-weight:bold;\'>' + b + '</p>' + h);
}
```

Any hints to make this togglable would be great.

Comment: Just FYI, the `void(...)` parts of that are nonsense. Just remove the `void(` and `)`, they serve **zero** purpose.

Comment: I know that part. This isn't my code

Comment: You said, but you also seemed to be new to JS, so...

Comment: I am not new, I will admit I am not as up to speed with it as other devs are - I haven't coded seriously in 5 years

Answer (score 1):

with is attempting to block scope your variable before block scoping was a thing :), it has nothing to do with your loop.

It is saying inside this code block start at `document.all[nIx5Bs].style` and any variable referenced (`backgroundColor`) is appended to that point.
More modern code would use `let` and `const` to block scope

```
for (let i = 0, max = document.all.length; i < max; i++) {
  let doc = document.all[i];

  if (doc.tagName === 'a') { 
    let style = doc.style; 
    if (style.backgroundColor !== 'yellow') {
      style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
      continue;
    }
    style.backgroundColor = document.bgColor;
  }
}
```